# I want to replace innerHTML() call in a Firefox overlay addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I am maintaining an overlay add-on for Firefox. To pass Mozilla's Add-on validation process I have to replace `innerHTML()` calls manipulating the content of a DOM element.

I create a new cell of a table and would like to set the content using this approach:

```
var newCell = tbl.rows[row].insertCell(col);
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
newCell.appendChild(div);
```

Error message is:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node.

EventTargetChild.prototype.handleEvent@resource://gre/modules/RemoteAddonsChild.jsm:461:5

EventTargetChild/this.capturingHandler@resource://gre/modules/RemoteAddonsChild.jsm:431:38
```

Adding log messages between the lines show that the type of the new `cell` and the `div` element are different:

```
var newCell = tbl.rows[row].insertCell(col);
console.log("cell-0: " + newCell);
var div = document.createElement('div');
console.log("div-0: " + div);
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
console.log("div-1: " + div);
console.log("cell-1: " + newCell);
newCell.appendChild(div);
console.log("cell-2: " + newCell);
```

the log messages are:

```
cell-0: [object CPOW [object HTMLTableCellElement]]
div-0: [object XULElement]
div-1: [object XULElement]
cell-1: [object CPOW [object HTMLTableCellElement]]
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, not helping here, but I'm using FF 48 and this works: https://jsfiddle.net/pj2eugLh/

Comment: You are using [`HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) to try to insert nodes into an XUL document. It appears to have created HTML elements instead of XUL elements. We are going to need more information about the `<document>` you are inserting into and how it has been manipulated previously. A link to the current version of the add-on wo9uld be helpful.

Comment: @blex, This is being inserted into an XUL document. It will not be possible to accurately prototype it using an HTML based site (e.g. jsfiddle.net). Testing XUL would require the file to be local to the machine (XUL Explorer), or using a `chrome://` URI within a Mozilla based application.

Comment: Also, when you mention "Mozilla's Add-on validation process" are you talking about the automated validation, or that the person doing the review of your add-on had a problem with you using `innerHTML`?  The issues with `innerHTML` are primarily security, which depends on the source of the text you are adding. If you the text is completely sourced from within your add-on, it should be able to pass review (you may have to explain to them what you are doing).

Comment: @Makyen, thanks a lot for your advice to look at `document`. I wasn't aware that I can't just use `document`. Apparently it is not the same as using the `document` I got back from the event I have to register my add-on to. Every element I create now based on this `document` is a `CPOW object` and it works.

Comment: @kabeleced, I'm glad what I wrote pointed you in a direction which was able to resolve your issue. One of the things that confuses many people when coming from writing webpage JavaScript (page scripts) is that in an add-on there are many `<document>` and `<window>` elements to which your `document` and `window` variables may refer. In addition, in the more powerful add-on environments (e.g overlay/legacy, bootstrap, and add-on SDK) the `window` and `document` variables may not even be defined, unless you define them.

Comment: @Makyen document not being the same as another document also happens in regular HTML if you operate on iframes or popup windows, especially when operating across xml vs. html boundaries. So those pitfalls aren't really specific to addon environments.

Comment: @the8472, True.  I did not mean to imply that such issues were exclusive to add-ons; merely that a good number of people, when programming add-ons, end up with issues relating to what, if anything, the `document` and `window` variables are referring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cell-0: [object CPOW [object HTMLTableCellElement]]

A CPOW is a [cross process object wrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Cross_Process_Object_Wrappers), which means it comes from a child process, or at least from a message passing API. You're not accessing the DOM in an [e10s-safe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Working_with_multiprocess_Firefox) way.

> div-0: [object XULElement]

Morecover you're creating a XUL element (a mozilla-specific XML namespace) and attempting to insert it in a HTML Document. This means you're operating across document boundaries (the CPOW already implies as much). The `document` object in your local scope is not the [ownerDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/ownerDocument) of `tbl`.

So even if the cross-process issue didn't exist you would still be using the DOM incorrectly.

---

If you want to interact with the DOM of content documents you should use the [message manager and frame scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Working_with_multiprocess_Firefox#Using_the_Message_Manager). They are the low-level primitives underpinning Addon SDK and webextension content scripts.

Additionally you can set the `<em:multiprocessCompatible>true</em:multiprocessCompatible>` [flag in the install.rdf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#multiprocessCompatible) which will disable compatibility shims or enable `dom.ipc.shims.enabledWarnings` in about:config, which should result in warnings/errors being thrown sooner if you're attempting to access any unsafe API.